# gRPC Allow two clients to talk to each other

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-web

I recently started learning how to do microservices architecture and I wanted to use gRPC instead of REST for my forward-facing APIs. I've looked around and tried to find a node.js example of two clients exchanging information (basically calling the other's API) and I haven't found much. I'm not sure if it's something that I'm misunderstanding or that I'm missing. I have two services

Right now I have this basic proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package basic;

service Basic {
  rpc PrintData(DataRequest) returns (DataReply) {}
}

message DataRequest {
  string name = 1;
  int32 age = 2;
}

message DataReply {
  string message = 1;
  int32 age = 2;
}
```

and want microservice A to be able to request `name` and `age` from microservice B. I can coordinate a client to server communication, but I'm not entirely sure how you would make two clients exchange information through their respective gRPC APIs. I'm currently using node to just get communication from the client to the server. Any help or links would be greatly helpful

Comment: IIUC to use grpc client stub you need to establish a connection to a grpc server and the server has to be running the server process. Client to Client communication is not possible I think. Unless you make all the nodes run a server and client process, in which case there would be no distinction between client and server processes.

Comment: So then how do you do microservices with gRPC? If the client nodes can't call each other's APIs, then I'm not sure how communication between services is done

Comment: If a client on node A wants to call "client node" B's API, you basically need a server on node B. Clients and servers can co-locate on the same "node", but there is still a distinction between them. There is a question about how client on node A discovers the address of the server on node B. This falls into the "service discovery" category and "service mesh" is the popular solution for that.

Comment: Ohhh! Okay, that helps a lot! I got the service discovery down, I just wasn't sure how to get them to actually call each other's API. But that make sense now